# Recreate a plot without data

Tags: r, ggplot2

Is there a way to create a figure similar to the one below without having any data on this?

[image]

Comment: Do you have any idea how that function is created?

Comment: @Quinten thanks according to the paper it suggests that as Socioeconomic position increases the corresponding exposure dimishes

Comment: Do you have a mathematical equation? This can be implemented in your plot.

Comment: @Quinten I don't have, sorry

Comment: Check out the digitize R package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the arrows you can use this code: `arrow = arrow(length = unit(0.5, "cm"))` in a `geom_segment`. It is a bit tricky without any numbers, but maybe you want something like this:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot() + 
  geom_abline(slope = 1) +
  geom_curve(aes(x = 0, y = 0, xend = 1, yend = 1), curvature = -0.4) +
  geom_curve(aes(x = 0, y = 1, xend = 1, yend = 0.1), curvature = 0.4, linetype = "dashed") +
  geom_segment(aes(x=0.9,y=0.98,xend=0.9,yend=0.12), arrow = arrow(length = unit(0.5, "cm"))) +
  geom_segment(aes(x=0.02,y=0.85,xend=0.02,yend=0.23), arrow = arrow(length = unit(0.5, "cm"))) +
  annotate("text", x = 0.5, y = 0.5, label = "Line of Equality", angle = 45, vjust = 2) +
  annotate("text", x = 0.25, y = 0.75, label = "Income (etc.)", angle = 45, vjust = 2) +
  annotate("text", x = 1.2, y = 0.1, label = "Corresponding\nExposure", angle = 0) +
  labs(x = "Individuals Neighbourhoods\nAcross Space", y = "Scoioeconomic Position") +
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0, 1.3)) +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(axis.text = element_blank())
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 6):

You could do something like this. You could add another `geom_curve` and a couple of `geom_vline`s.

```r
library(tidyverse)

ggplot() +
  geom_abline() +
  geom_curve(aes(x = 0, y = 0, xend = 1, yend = 1), curvature = -0.4) +
  annotate("text", x = 0.5, y = 0.5, label = "Line of Equality", angle = 35, vjust = 2) +
  labs(x = "Individuals Neighbourhoods\nAcross Space", y = "Scoioeconomic Position") +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(axis.text = element_blank())
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-04-27 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>